# Multiplying 2 values gives the original value but dividing the same values gives the right answer

Tags: powershell, csv, numbers, multiplication

I have 2 values that I can not get to multiply together and get the right answer. Here is my very simple code:

```
$data | ForEach-Object {
            $newMHV = ($_.'North' * $_.'Measured Heat Value') 
            $_.'North BTU' = $newMHV
            $_               # Output the modified row
            } | Export-Csv $AFw -NoTypeInformation
```

The first time through the loop `$_.'North'` = `1648` and `$_.'Measured Heat Value'` = `1.022`
`$newMHV` should be `1684.xxx`. `$newMVH` always shows `1648` on the first value then changes to the second value.

When I change the calculation to division, I get the correct value.

I have tried trimming the values, etc. but I cant find it.
I may need to convert them to a numeric but why would it work when I divide the values?

Note: `$data` is a `.csv` file that I have imported.

Comment: Your problem description is quite confusing - when you do `1648 / 1.022` you get a value higher than 1648.0? Is that correctly understood? If not, then please include [enough code to actually reproduce the behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) you're seeing

Comment: try casting `int`: `[int] $_.'North' * $_.'Measured Heat Value'`. if the left hand side is `int` it will also coerce the right hand side so no need to add to both

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon That's only true for comparison operators, arithmetic operators have slightly different semantics - `$int * $double` always produces a double for example

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen didnt notice `'Measured Heat Value'` was a double. casting `[double]` then should work

Comment: I guess that depends on what the actual problem is - `1648 * 1.022` will never be between 1648 and 1649 either, `1.022` is too high a coefficient

Comment: Casting to double worked like a charm! Thanks. SB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crucial pointer is in the comments:

- **Data imported from a CSV file** is invariably **`[string]`-typed**.
- Thus, you must **ensure that (at least) your LHS operand is of type `[double]` (or another suitable numeric type) to make your calculation work** as expected (PowerShell will coerce the RHS to `[double]` too, as needed):

```bash
$newMHV = [double] $_.'North' * $_.'Measured Heat Value'
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

- The **`*` operator also operates on *strings***: if the LHS is a `[string]` and the RHS is / can be coerced to a *number*, the string is "multiplied" (duplicated) by the RHS number; that is, if the number is `$n`, you get the concatenation of `$n` copies of the LHS string;<sup>[1]</sup> e.g.:

  ```bash
  # -> 'abcabc'
  'abc' * 2
  ```

  - In your case, the RHS, `'1.022'` didn't represent an *integer*, which means that PowerShell *implicitly* did the following: `[int] '1.022'` - which yields `1`; therefore, your "calculation" was ultimately the equivalent of the following, which amounted to a virtual *no-op*:

    ```bash
    '1648' * 1 # -> '1648'
    ```
- By contrast, the **`/` operator operates *only* on numbers**, so it coerces even `[string]`-typed operands to a number (which may situationally be an integer data type such as `[int]` or `[double]`, as needed).

  ```bash
  # -> a [double] with value 2.5 - even though both operands are *strings*
  '10' / '4'
  ```

---

<sup>[1] It follows that if `$n` is `1`, you get (an identical copy of) the string itself, and if it is `0`, you get the *empty string* (`''`).</sup>

Comment: That is a terrific explanation! Thank you so much. SB